# Monotouch button mouse over

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, xamarin.ios, uikit

I'm new to MonoTouch and need some pointers on how to listen for a simple MouseOver event for a button. The goal is to have a grid of buttons and track the movement while passing over these buttons. Actually it doesn't have to be buttons at all, just something that I can manipulate and display a letter in.

For an example, look at WordRoom for Windows 8/WP7 if you're running windows.

Any pointer would be nice! :)

EDIT: What I have in WP7 is a UserControl using XAML that I draw the rectangles on. I then listen to the ManipulationStarted-event to know when I swipe over it. That's what I would like here to. The result I'm looking for is in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13IczvA7Ipo

PLEASE NOTE that this is not an attempt to promote the game but to get the basic technical solution for how to do the same in MonoTouch. And yes, I wrote WordRoom so it's not gonna be a rip-of. :)

Thanks

Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you derive from `UIView` can overwrite the Methods `TouchesBegan`, `TouchesMoved` and `TouchesEnded`.

Here's an example for `TouchesBegan`

```
    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;

        if (touch != null && touch.View != this) {
            var rp = touch.LocationInView (touch.View);
            var p = new PointF(touch.View.Frame.X + rp.X, touch.View.Frame.Y + rp.Y);

            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Another option would to the usage of a GestureRecognizer:

[Using UIGestureRecognizer in MonoTouch](http://dan.clarke.name/2012/08/using-uigesturerecognizer-in-monotouch/)

[Generic Gesture Recognizer](https://gist.github.com/1453770)

Comment: I guess I have to track TouchesBegan on the parent control since there seem to be no way to track a touch that began outside the control?